# Importing Subpackage by Assignment in Python

Tags: python, pandas, python-import, assignment-operator

I often see redundant imports in code like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series as s
from pandas import DataFrame as df
```

I get that it's simpler to use s and df as shorthand rather than typing out pd.DataFrame everytime, but would it not be preferrable to just assign pd.DataFrame to df rather than importing it (since you essentially already imported it with its parent)?

For instance, I think it could be cleaned up like this:

```
import pandas as pd
s, df = pd.Series, pd.DataFrame
```

Is there any drawbacks to doing it this way? I'm still fairly new to Python so I'm wondering if I'm missing something here.